# How do I prevent TEXT() from rounding numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-formatting

I'm trying to display a percentage to 1 decimal place, in the middle of a text string using

`="..." & TEXT(A1/A2,"0.0%") & "..."` (simplified)

But my values keep rounding to whole numbers like `5` instead of `4.9` for  `4.99995`

I have looked at the [official Microsoft documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20D5AC4D-7B94-49FD-BB38-93D29371225C) but as far as I can tell `"0.0%"` should do what I want, it doesn't mention rounding there at all.

I have also tried `"0.#%"` as my format string, but it has the same rounding issue, I do not want to use `"0.####%"` because I don't want to display multiple decimal places.

### Example output

```
Input      Output     Desired Output
4.99     ...5.0%...     ...4.9%...
4.89     ...4.9%...     ...4.8%...
4.5      ...4.5%...     ...4.5%...
4.55     ...4.6%...     ...4.5%...
4.54     ...4.5%...     ...4.5%...
4.8994   ...4.9%...     ...4.8%...
```

Comment: What happens with `4.8994`?

Comment: `TEXT(INT(A/B*1000)/1000,"0.0%")`

Comment: @MátéJuhász pretty gross, and what I was hoping to not resort to, but it works. I was hoping there would be a *real* solution for me to use, as opposed to this hack

Comment: "But my values keep rounding to whole numbers like 5 instead of 4.9 for  4.99995" - that behaviour is the commonly accepted one, when 4.999 is rounded people expect to see 5.0 (0.001 difference) rather than 4.9 (0.099 difference, 99 times bigger)

Comment: this is not a hack, this is a solution for a pretty uncommon problem, as I explained above, what you try to do is not the one people generally do.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Sure, when people are rounding, but I am not rounding, nor do I want to round! For `99.999999992` displaying `100%` is highly misleading while `99.9` while less close to the real answer is much more helpful

Comment: other approach could be to use ROUNDDOWN or TRUNC, they behave similarly, difference is in their behaviour with negative numbers (TRUNC rounds to 0, ROUNDDOWN rounds to smaller integer)

Comment: @MátéJuhász `TRUNC` is exactly what I was looking for, solution is `="..." & TRUNC((A1/A2) * 100, 1) & "%..."`